# Hive query using lookup table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables,

- Customer table with JSON Serde whih contains just one column
- other is a look-up table to locate customer level (1,2,3,4)

**Customer Table**

```
{ 
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Info" : {
      "Address": "111 Main Street",
      "ID": 2222
  }
}
```

**Look-up table** 
has 2 columns, customer ID and level.  For Example

```
ID     Level
1111    1
1123    4
2234    1
```

How do I write a Hive query to identify all customers that are level 1 from my customer table?

Thanks

Comment: what is stopping you from joining this two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Extract `ID` from JSON using `get_json_object()` and join with lookup table, add filtering.

Demo:

```
 select s.cust_name, s.Address, s.ID, lkp.level
    from
        (select
               get_json_object(json_col,'$.Info.ID') as ID,
               get_json_object(json_col,'$.Name') as cust_name,
               get_json_object(json_col,'$.Info.Address') as Address
   from        
               ( --replace this subquery with your table
                select '{"Name": "John Doe","Info" : {"Address": "111 Main Street","ID": 2222}}' as json_col)s 
        ) s
   left join    
            ( --replace this subquery with your table
            select stack(4,
                         1111,    1,
                         1123,    4,
                         2234,    1,
                         2222,    3
                        )  as (ID, Level) 
            )lkp on s.ID=lkp.ID
where lkp.Level !=1     --filter out level 1 
   or lkp.level is null --this is to allow records without corresponding level in lkp 
;
```

Result:

```
OK
cust_name       address id      level
John Doe        111 Main Street 2222    3
Time taken: 31.469 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  How do I update your solution to remove all customer with customer level =1 from Customer Table?

Comment: @Chopstick Added filter in the query